# Use StringBuffer to replace substring throughout a long string

Tags: java, replace, whitespace, stringbuffer

I need to compose a long string (4324 characters) and want to use StringBuffer for this purpose. Most of the string will be whitespace but some portions contain orderdetails. They must appear at certain positions. This string will be fed into an accounting-system.

I am initializing the string with whitespace (" ") and setting the length, in this example to 64.

```
public class BytteTekst {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String t1 = "Hej, jeg æder blåbærsyltetøj!";
        String t2 = "foo";

        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(" ");
        s.setLength(64);

        System.out.println(t1.length());

        s.replace(0, t1.length(), t1);
        System.out.println(s);

        s.replace(t1.length() + 10, t1.length() + t2.length() + 10, t2);
        System.out.println(s);

        System.out.println(s.length());
    }
}
```

The output from `java BytteTekst` is

```
29
Hej, jeg æder blåbærsyltetøj!
Hej, jeg æder blåbærsyltetøj!foo
64
```

When I replace() string `foo` it appears just after the first replace(). I need to have some whitespace to get a result similar like this:

```
29
Hej, jeg æder blåbærsyltetøj!
Hej, jeg æder blåbærsyltetøj!          foo
64
```

Am I using StringBuffer the wrong way? Is it silently ignoring the whitespace I want to add?

Comment: As an aside, you should use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. The API is largely identical, but it avoids unnecessary synchronization.

Comment: Thank you, I will use that. It will not be accessed from outside so I don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that

```
s.setLength(64);
```

changes the length to 64, filling the new space with `\0` characters: its contents will be:

```
[' ', '\0', '\0', ... '\0'] (1 space, 63 \0s)
```

After your second replace, the contents will be:

```
['H', 'e', 'j', ... 't', 'ø', 'j', '!', '\0' (x10), 'f', 'o', 'o', '\0', ...]
```

So there *is* whitespace there, it's just non-printed whitespace.

If you want to fill your string with spaces, rather than `'\0'`, you can either loop through the string with a plain for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) s.setCharAt(i, ' ');
```

or hard-code a string of spaces with the correct length:

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("           "); // Not 64 chars - count carefully!
```

or you can "simply" initialize with a `char[]` filled with spaces:

```
char[] fill = new char[64];
Arrays.fill(fill, ' ');
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(new String(fill));
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It makes sense now.